# Does 37signals OAuth provider work with localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, 37-signals

I am using omniauth-37signals and have set the redirect_uri to `http://localhost:3000/auth/highrise/callback` in developer.37signals.com

I am getting:
`:error: Provided redirect_uri is not approved`

But if I change the url to something different from localhost it works and asks for access.

Is the API restricted only for 'real' addresses, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

lvh.me worked for me instead of localhost. It points back to 127.0.0.1